# mysql select default order with limit select * from mytable limit m, n;

Tags: mysql

in mysql, if you do

```
select * from mytable limit m, n;
```

will you always get the same rows back  assuming the table is not changing(no add delete, but some update)?
for example, if you do

```
select * from mytable limit 10000, 10000
```

from various clients/threads, will you consistently get the same results back?

Comment: It depends on the columns in table. If there is a `PRIMARY KEY`, mysql will, by default order by that column, otherwise, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

As stated under section 20.2 <direct select statement: multiple rows>, subsection "General Rules" of
 the [SQL-92 specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> ```
> 4) If an <order by clause> is not specified, then the ordering of
>    the rows of Q is implementation-dependent.
> ```

The best implementation-specific documentation on this point that I can find in the MySQL manual is under [Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sorting-rows.html):

> You may have noticed in the preceding examples that the result rows are displayed in no particular order. It is often easier to examine query output when the rows are sorted in some meaningful way. To sort a result, use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Suffice to say that without explicit documentation to the contrary, one cannot rely on MySQL to consistently return records in the same order unless a suitably explicit `ORDER BY` clause is given (even though, in my experience, it always is consistent).